# Usage of 'stand'

Tags: word-usage

I heard a person saying
 'The guest room stood empty' 
It sounded a bit weird to me perhaps because English isn't my first language. Buy what does it mean here? Obviously the room stands. Can't we just say :
'The room was empty?

Answer (score 1):

It is a way of emphasising and underlining the fact that the room was empty. ***As things stood, the room was empty***.

It might be used in circumstances where you wanted to draw attention to the room's emptiness. For example:

*Notwithstanding their having put four camp beds in the drawing room, and two on the balcony, where the younger members of the family were able to sleep quite comfortably on the summer evening, **the guest room stood empty***.

Comment: Can we the automobile stood at the end of the street?